# bookmark panel not showing scrollbar on adobe embedded

Tags: adobe-embed-api

I am refereing below document for abobe annotation.

https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/docs/overview/pdf-embed-api/howtos_ui/#

I am using below configuration to enable or disable the icons,

viewerConfig = {
defaultViewMode:"FIT_WIDTH",
showAnnotationTools: true,
enableAnnotationAPIs: true,
showLeftHandPanel: true,
includePDFAnnotations: false,
enableFormFilling: false,
dockPageControls: false,
};

My problem is i am not able to scrollbar on bookmark panel.How do i enable is?

[image]

Comment: Hi - can you share the URL where this is demonstrated? Or share a PDF with me having this issue?

Comment: Sorry Raymond, i can not share pdf. And i dont have any code. You can use codepan code from https://codepen.io/practicalPDF/pen/PoZLWeq here.  But in this eg they dont have bookmark updated pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like you've found an issue with the CSS being used to render bookmarks in the Embed viewer. I'm going to file this internally as a bug. As of now though I do not believe there is a workaround.